# Calculating $\min\{f(x,y)\ |\ (x,y)\in A\}$ given $\min\{f(x,y)\ |\ (x,y)\in\partial A\}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ 0\leq x\leq 2, 0\leq y\leq 3\}$ and $f:(x,y)\mapsto x^4+y^4-4x-32y+30$. It's given that $\min\{f(x,y)\ |\ (x,y)\in\partial A\}=-18$. What is $\min\{f(x,y)\ |\ (x,y)\in A\}$?

So by the extreme value theorem, such value is indeed well-defined, however I'm having a hard time seeing how one could find it. I feel like the information that $f$ attains a minimumvalue of $-18$ at the boundary of $A$, hint to their being a general way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum is $-21=f(1,2)$. That's because $(1,2)$ is the only point in the interior of $A$ where the gradient of $f$ is $(0,0)$ (actually, it's the only point *at all* with that property). So, since the minimum of $f$ in $\partial A$ is $-18$, the minimum in $A$ is $-21$.